# Many entry fields, only one db request?

Tags: database, elementcriteriamodel, performance

Craft 101: I have entries with many different fields, so I'm doing something like this:

```
{% set var = craft.entries.section('foo').slug('bar').first() %}

{% if var %}
  {{ var.field1 }}
  {{ var.field2 }}
  {{ var.field3 }}
  etc...
{% endif %}
```

Does Craft fetch the entry only once or every time the variable is called? I'm guessing only once but I'm not too sure, and some entries have 50+ fields.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The statement is only executed once.

You are essentially creating an [elementCriteriaModel](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/elementcriteriamodel), returning the first element using the `.first()` parameter (which in this case is an [Entry Model](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/entrymodel)), and storing it in a variable; which you then can use to access your field values.

If you want to further increase performance you can wrap the whole block in a [cache](http://buildwithcraft.com/docs/templating/cache) tag, which will speed up subsequent requests.

Comment: Thanks! I'm guessing this also applies if said variables are actually called further down in other "included" templates?

Comment: Yes and no — it applies anywhere that the variable is still in scope. Variables defined in a template do not automatically carry over to included templates. You would have to explicitly include the template using the `with` clause (i.e. `{% include 'template.html' with {'var': var} %}`).

Comment: Interesting consideration, I'll look into that. Thanks.